# SQL query for excluding a key value matching record for a specific condition

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've a table as below :

```
declare @temp table(
PkId int,
DetailId int,

Type int
)


insert into @temp(PkId,DetailId,[Type])
select 1,1,5
union
select 2,1,3
union
select 3,1,4
union
select 4,2,5
union
select 5,3,5
union
select 6,3,3

select * from @temp order by DetailId
```

returns me

```
PkId    DetailId    TypeID

1       1       5

2       1       3

3       1       4

4       2       5

5       3       5

6       3       3
```

Conditions for getting the records are

1. For the given 'DetaildID' if only TypeID 5 is present, shall return 5
2. If 3 or 4 are present then exclude 5

I'm expecting the output as

```
2   1   3

3   1   4

4   2   5

6   3   3
```

Please help me with a query.

Comment: And what have you tried? Hint: you may want to use a WHERE clause.

Comment: Help you with what query? Post your query.

Comment: Your conditions are very confusing. Can you rewrite more clearly?

Comment: I tried with CTE and Pivot in it. Cannot post the query as it is so added sample data and sample query. Anyway thanks for the reply, I got the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select pkid, detailid, type
from temp
where type <> 5
group by pkid, detailid, type
union
select pkid, detailid, type
from temp 
where detailid not in (
select detailid
from temp
where type <> 5
group by pkid, detailid, type

)
order by pkid
```

[TEST](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0c1b8/20)

Comment: Downvote for a code dump with no explanation as an answer to a bad question.

Comment: I don't understand why here is a down vote? And what is the bad question? This answer is just perfect and solved my problem. Thanks Horaciux for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the meaning of the rules, if not some sql puzzle, but it's possible to use the windowing function of SQLServer 2008 to write them

```
WITH C AS (
  SELECT pkId, DetailId, typeID
       , _34 = SUM(CASE WHEN TypeID IN (3, 4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
             OVER (PARTITION BY DetailId)
       , _5 =  SUM(TypeID) OVER (PARTITION BY DetailId)
  FROM   Table1
)
SELECT pkId, DetailId, typeID
FROM   C
WHERE  (_34 > 0 AND TypeID <> 5)
   OR  (_5 = 5)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ad78b/5)</kbd>

For every row of a `DetaildID` group:

- _34 is positive if there is a `TypeID` 3 or a `TypeID` 4 in the group
- _5 will be 5 if the only `TypeID` in the group is 5

Those value are used in the `WHERE` condition of the main query to filter the data. The second condition `(_5 = 5)` don't check for the value of `_34` as it's already implicit.
There should probably be a fallback condition in case `TypeID` has a value different from 3, 4 or 5, the query as it is will return them in a group with 3 or 4 `(_34 > 0 AND TypeID <> 5)` and remove it otherwise `(_34 = 0 AND _5 <> 5)`.